# Use navigator to automatically route in the form flow

Tags: flutter

How can I build an automatic routing at start of my app? I build a Route generator to handle the navigation routes across the different forms and instantiated it in the main function:
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(S.current);
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
        initialRoute: '/',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The RouteGenerator points to the different widgets

```
    class RouteGenerator {
      static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
        final args = settings.arguments;
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Authenticate());
      case '/loading':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoadingScreen());
      case '/signIn':
        if (args is Function) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignIn(toggleView: args));
        }
        return _underConstruction();
      case '/register':
        if (args is Function) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Register(toggleView: args));
        }
        return _underConstruction();
      case '/home':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Home());
      default:
        return _underConstruction();
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to build logic in a statefull widget it doesn't accept the navigatoer as return and adding the result in a dynamic variable doesn't help.

```
class Authenticate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticateState createState() => _AuthenticateState();
}

class _AuthenticateState extends State<Authenticate> {
  bool showSignIn = true;

  void toggleView() {
    setState(() => showSignIn = !showSignIn);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    dynamic route = (user == null)
        ? Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(showSignIn ? '/signIn' : '/register')
        : Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
    return route;
  }
}
```

How would you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal option would be to set the `signIn` or `register` route as your home route and have a button to switch between them. The method can replace your current route and push another:

```
void swapRoute(String route){
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(route);
}
```

Comment: Thanks João foor the feedback. It true I can set the navigator on the onPressed function of the button to move from register to navigate and back. 
The app will at start launch the homescreen when the user is known or go to the authenticate screen:
`
dynamic route = (user == null)
        ? Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/signIn')
        : Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
`
How can I do that with the navigator?

Comment: You don't need to use the Navigator directly in that case. You can just return one Widget or the other on your `initialRoute` property of the `MaterialApp`, depending if your user is already loggedin or not.